# Capturing Remote desktop request

Tags: remote-desktop

I have an app running at the Machine-A, now Machine-B is requesting a remote desktop to Machine-A. The app running at Machine-A needs to capture this request and log it. Is this possible through either C++/C#.

I have googled to find, if there's any widows message being transmitted, but in vain. Also I won't be able to bind to the port 3389, as its already being used by Remote Desktop server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can receive notifications of various remote desktop events via [ServiceBase.OnSessionChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onsessionchange.aspx) (if your .NET application is running as a Windows service) or [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). To get additional information about the new session, you can use other WTS* functions, or the [Cassia library](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/) from a .NET application.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you cannot bind, but you CAN sniff traffic - read for raw sockets and/or PCAP driver.